# Why are there missing components in AWS Toolkit for Eclipse 2 when I try to install it into Eclipse using Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am using the latest Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers, Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200.

When I got to Help->Eclipse Marketplace or to Help->Install New Software in and try to install AWS Toolkit for Eclipse 2, I get an error message saying:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

In details, it says:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201807201743)
>   Missing requirement: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar 1.0.0.v201807201743) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: AWS CodeStar Plugin 1.0.0.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201807201743)
>   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar [1.0.0.v201807201743,1.0.0.v201807201743]

[image]

When I try the same procedure again, excluding AWS CodeStar Plugin from trying to install, I get the same message except the details show that a the installation process could not satisfy a different dependency:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201807201743)
>   Missing requirement: AWS Toolkit Core Plugin 2.3.1.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.3.1.v201807201743) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201807201743 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201807201743)
>   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.0.0

[image]

I tried to do the same thing in Windows 10, and I got the same results.

Here are the instructions I followed: [Set up the Toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html)

I tried the same thing on macOS with an older 2018 version of Eclipse for Java EE and Report, and I got the same results.

How do I fix this? Is that missing requirement something that I should have installed beforehand?

Comment: `org.eclipse.m2e.core` is the Eclipse Maven integration. Install New Software should be able to find that as long as you have 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' selected. Some Eclipse installs even include it by default.

Comment: @greg-449 I did have that item checked.